# SSH intrusion suspected: Logwatch report versus SSH log file entries

Tags: ssh, intrusion

My Web server's Logwatch report shows `ssh` and `su` activity that should not be there:

```
sshd:
   Sessions Opened:
      deployer: 45 Time(s)

su:
   Sessions Opened:
      root -> deployer: 8 Time(s)
      deployer -> root: 5 Time(s)

Users logging in through sshd:
   deployer:
      <SOME_IP_ADDRESS>: 45 times
```

But the server's `ssh` logs show no activity for `<SOME_IP_ADDRESS>` or this `deployer` user during the given day. This would lead me to believe that there is an intruder, who has erased all ssh log lines mentioning  before quitting.

But Logwatch does not scan logs in real-time, but only once a day, which means it shouldn't have caught the above activity if the log lines were erased by the attacker.

- Could Logwatch have reported nonsense?
- What's the most probable situation here?
- Is it definitely time to set up a new server?
- How would you handle the situation?

## *EDIT I and II: More info below*

It seems clear now, there definitely was an intrusion.

Can somebody see/explain how exactly this must have unfolded? (The User and Group names listed as "new" already existed before.)

*EDIT I:*

```
 --------------------- pam_unix Begin ------------------------ 

 passwd:
    Password changed:
       deployer: 1 Time(s)
       root: 1 Time(s)

 --------------------- Connections (secure-log) Begin ------------------------ 

 New Users:
    deployer (1000)
    mysql (105)
    postfix (106)

 New Groups:
    rvm (1000)
    mysql (115)
    postfix (116)

 Added User to group:
    rvm:
       deployer

 Changed password expiry for users:
    mysql : 1 Time(s)
    postfix : 1 Time(s)

 **Unmatched Entries**
    chfn: changed user 'mysql' information: 1 Time(s)
    usermod: add 'deployer' to shadow group 'rvm': 1 Time(s)
    usermod: change user 'postfix' password: 1 Time(s)

 --------------------- SSHD Begin ------------------------ 

 SSHD Killed: 4 Time(s)

 SSHD Started: 16 Time(s)

 Users logging in through sshd:
    deployer:
       <SOME_UNKNOWN_IP>: 10 times
       <SOME_UNKNOWN_OTHER_IP> (<SOME_UNKNOWN_HOST>): 1 time
    root:
       <SOME_UNKNOWN_OTHER_IP> (<SOME_UNKNOWN_HOST>): 1 time
```

*EDIT II:* (maybe this tells a story?)

```
 --------------------- Kernel Begin ------------------------ 


 WARNING:  Kernel Errors Present
    acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM ...:  4 Time(s)

 1 Time(s):  --- wd:2 rd:2
 1 Time(s):  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sda3
 1 Time(s):  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:sdb3
 4 Time(s): #2  #3  #4  #5  #6  #7
 2 Time(s): --- wd:2 rd:2
 4 Time(s): ... bit width:              48
 4 Time(s): ... event mask:             000000070000000f
 4 Time(s): ... fixed-purpose events:   3
 4 Time(s): ... generic registers:      4
 4 Time(s): ... max period:             0000ffffffffffff
 4 Time(s): ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
 4 Time(s): ... version:                3
 4 Time(s): .... node  #0, CPUs:        #1
 4 Time(s): ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
 4 Time(s): 0 base 0000000000 mask 7F80000000 write-back
 4 Time(s): 00000-9FFFF write-back
 4 Time(s): 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
 4 Time(s): 00:05: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
 4 Time(s): 1 base 0080000000 mask 7FC0000000 write-back
 4 Time(s): 2 base 0100000000 mask 7F00000000 write-back
 4 Time(s): 3 base 0200000000 mask 7E00000000 write-back
 4 Time(s): 4 base 0400000000 mask 7C00000000 write-back
 4 Time(s): 5 base 0800000000 mask 7FC0000000 write-back
 4 Time(s): 6 base 00FF000000 mask 7FFF000000 write-protect
 4 Time(s): 7 disabled
 4 Time(s): 8 disabled
 4 Time(s): 9 disabled
 4 Time(s): A0000-BFFFF uncachable
 4 Time(s): ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20140424/hwxface-580)
 4 Time(s): ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
 4 Time(s): ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S3 S4 S5)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: APIC 0x00000000BEFED498 000112 (v03 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: All ACPI Tables successfully acquired
 4 Time(s): ACPI: BERT 0x00000000BEFEFC98 000030 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   00000001 INTL 00000001)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: BOOT 0x00000000BEFEFD98 000028 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Core revision 20140424
 4 Time(s): ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000BEFEED18 000080 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   00000001 INTL 00000001)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000BEFDD018 00F911 (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00000000 INTL 20120711)
 12 Time(s): ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
 4 Time(s): ACPI: EINJ 0x00000000BEFED798 000130 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   00000001 INTL 00000001)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: ERST 0x00000000BEFC9C98 000230 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   00000001 INTL 00000001)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
 4 Time(s): ACPI: FACP 0x00000000BEFED618 00010C (v05 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: FACS 0x00000000BEFEDF40 000040
 4 Time(s): ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000BEFEFB18 000044 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   00000000      00000000)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Fan [FAN0] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Fan [FAN1] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Fan [FAN2] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Fan [FAN3] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Fan [FAN4] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: HEST 0x00000000BEFC9F18 0000A8 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   00000001 INTL 00000001)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: HPET 0x00000000BEFEFE18 000038 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
 4 Time(s): ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x02] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
 4 Time(s): ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
 4 Time(s): ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
 4 Time(s): ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Interpreter enabled
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x06] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x05] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x07] enabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
 8 Time(s): ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
 4 Time(s): ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000BEFEFF18 00003C (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 *5 6 10 11 12 14 15)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-3e])
 4 Time(s): ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F0410 000024 (v02 INTEL )
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SPCR 0x00000000BEFEFD18 000050 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SPMI 0x00000000BEFEFB98 000040 (v05 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFB2018 009F93 (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00001000 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFCF018 000310 (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00003000 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFCF398 00033F (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00003000 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFCFA98 000348 (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00003000 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFD0018 003297 (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00003000 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFD4018 000AD8 (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00003000 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BEFD5018 00206F (v02 INTEL  DENLOW   00001000 INTL 20120711)
 1 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88081360C800 0003D3 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20120711)
 1 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF880813611800 0005AA (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20120711)
 1 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88081366AC00 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20120711)
 3 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF880813714000 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20120711)
 3 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF880813720000 0005AA (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20120711)
 3 Time(s): ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF880813AF0400 0003D3 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20120711)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (30 C)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
 4 Time(s): ACPI: WDDT 0x00000000BEFEFE98 000040 (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x00] uid[0x00] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x01] uid[0x01] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x02] uid[0x02] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x03] uid[0x03] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x04] uid[0x04] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x05] uid[0x05] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x06] uid[0x06] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: X2APIC (apic_id[0x07] uid[0x07] disabled)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000BEFEDD98 0000CC (v01 INTEL  DENLOW   06222004 INTL 20090903)
 4 Time(s): ACPI: bus type PCI registered
 4 Time(s): ACPI: bus type PNP registered
 4 Time(s): ACPI: bus type PNP unregistered
 4 Time(s): ACPI: bus type USB registered
 4 Time(s): AGP: Checking aperture...
 8 Time(s): AGP: No AGP bridge found
 4 Time(s): AMD AuthenticAMD
 4 Time(s): AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
 4 Time(s): Adding 16768892k swap on /dev/md0.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16768892k FS
 4 Time(s): AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
 4 Time(s): AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
 4 Time(s): AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
 4 Time(s): Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
 4 Time(s): BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009bbff] usable
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009bc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bc1c4fff] usable
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bc1c5000-0x00000000beb90fff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000beb91000-0x00000000beb96fff] ACPI NVS
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000beb97000-0x00000000becccfff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000beccd000-0x00000000becd0fff] ACPI NVS
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000becd1000-0x00000000becf1fff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000becf2000-0x00000000becf2fff] ACPI NVS
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000becf3000-0x00000000bed24fff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bed25000-0x00000000bef2efff] ACPI NVS
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bef2f000-0x00000000befeffff] ACPI data
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000beff0000-0x00000000beffffff] usable
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bf000000-0x00000000bfffffff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed19000-0x00000000fed19fff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff400000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
 4 Time(s): BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000083fffffff] usable
 4 Time(s): BRK [0x01fd3000, 0x01fd3fff] PGTABLE
 4 Time(s): BRK [0x01fd4000, 0x01fd4fff] PGTABLE
 4 Time(s): BRK [0x01fd5000, 0x01fd5fff] PGTABLE
 4 Time(s): BRK [0x01fd6000, 0x01fd6fff] PGTABLE
 4 Time(s): Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000095000] 95000 size 24576
 4 Time(s): Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
 4 Time(s): Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
 4 Time(s): Btrfs loaded
 4 Time(s): Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 8241746
 4 Time(s): C0000-C7FFF write-through
 4 Time(s): C8000-CBFFF write-protect
 4 Time(s): CC000-E7FFF uncachable
 4 Time(s): CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
 4 Time(s): CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
 4 Time(s): CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
 4 Time(s): Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
 4 Time(s): Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
 1 Time(s): Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 7183.19 BogoMIPS (lpj=14366392)
 1 Time(s): Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 7183.24 BogoMIPS (lpj=14366496)
 1 Time(s): Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 7183.80 BogoMIPS (lpj=14367600)
 1 Time(s): Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 7183.89 BogoMIPS (lpj=14367796)
 4 Time(s): Centaur CentaurHauls
 4 Time(s): Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-24-generic root=UUID=5c6f96b2-3f09-43d8-bd0c-a9558effe443 ro nomodeset nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
 4 Time(s): Consider also installing thermald for improved thermal control.
 4 Time(s): Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
 4 Time(s): DMA      [mem 0x00001000-0x00ffffff]
 4 Time(s): DMA zone: 21 pages reserved
 4 Time(s): DMA zone: 3994 pages, LIFO batch:0
 4 Time(s): DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
 4 Time(s): DMA32    [mem 0x01000000-0xffffffff]
 4 Time(s): DMA32 zone: 11976 pages used for memmap
 4 Time(s): DMA32 zone: 766421 pages, LIFO batch:31
 4 Time(s): DMI: Intel Corporation S1200RP/S1200RP, BIOS S1200RP.86B.01.04.0002.011020141517 01/10/2014
 4 Time(s): Dentry cache hash table entries: 4194304 (order: 13, 33554432 bytes)
 4 Time(s): Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
 4 Time(s): E8000-FFFFF write-protect
 4 Time(s): EDD information not available.
 4 Time(s): ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
 4 Time(s): ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
 4 Time(s): EXT4-fs (md1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
 4 Time(s): EXT4-fs (md1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
 4 Time(s): EXT4-fs (md2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
 4 Time(s): EXT4-fs (md2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
 4 Time(s): Early memory node ranges
 4 Time(s): Enabled IRQ remapping in x2apic mode
 4 Time(s): Enabled x2apic
 4 Time(s): Enabling x2apic
 4 Time(s): Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000083fffffff]
 4 Time(s): Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K (ffffffff81e82000 - ffffffff81e8a000)
 4 Time(s): Freeing initrd memory: 21244K (ffff880035672000 - ffff880036b31000)
 4 Time(s): Freeing unused kernel memory: 1360K (ffffffff81d2e000 - ffffffff81e82000)
 4 Time(s): Freeing unused kernel memory: 448K (ffff880001790000 - ffff880001800000)
 4 Time(s): Freeing unused kernel memory: 488K (ffff880001b86000 - ffff880001c00000)
 4 Time(s): GHES: APEI firmware first mode is enabled by APEI bit and WHEA _OSC.
 4 Time(s): HEST: Table parsing has been initialized.
 4 Time(s): HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xfed90000
 4 Time(s): Hierarchical RCU implementation.
 4 Time(s): HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
 4 Time(s): IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base  0xfed90000 IOMMU 0
 4 Time(s): IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 2, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
 4 Time(s): IPMI System Interface driver.
 4 Time(s): IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
 4 Time(s): IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
 4 Time(s): Initialise system trusted keyring
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys devices
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys memory
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
 4 Time(s): Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
 4 Time(s): Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x00000000-0x83fffffff]
 4 Time(s): Inode-cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes)
 4 Time(s): Intel GenuineIntel
 4 Time(s): Intel P-state driver initializing.
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 0
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 1
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 2
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 3
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 4
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 5
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 6
 4 Time(s): Intel pstate controlling: cpu 7
 4 Time(s): KERNEL supported cpus:
 4 Time(s): Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-24-generic root=UUID=5c6f96b2-3f09-43d8-bd0c-a9558effe443 ro nomodeset nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
 4 Time(s): Key type asymmetric registered
 4 Time(s): Key type big_key registered
 4 Time(s): Key type dns_resolver registered
 4 Time(s): Key type encrypted registered
 4 Time(s): Key type trusted registered
 4 Time(s): Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 1024, 1GB 4
 4 Time(s): Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 1024
 4 Time(s): Linux agpgart interface v0.103
 4 Time(s): Linux version 3.16.0-24-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) ) #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:07:32 UTC 2014 (Ubuntu 3.16.0-24.32-generic 3.16.4)
 4 Time(s): Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 3c8840d17bdf902e171e23b4bbc2728eb694c70a'
 4 Time(s): Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
 4 Time(s): MTRR default type: uncachable
 4 Time(s): MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
 4 Time(s): MTRR variable ranges enabled:
 1 Time(s): Magic number: 6:19:677
 1 Time(s): Magic number: 6:398:70
 1 Time(s): Magic number: 6:501:171
 1 Time(s): Magic number: 6:822:78
 4 Time(s): Memory: 32860320K/33490364K available (7731K kernel code, 1200K rwdata, 3608K rodata, 1360K init, 1308K bss, 630044K reserved)
 4 Time(s): Mount-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
 4 Time(s): Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
 4 Time(s): Movable zone start for each node
 4 Time(s): NET: Registered protocol family 1
 4 Time(s): NET: Registered protocol family 10
 4 Time(s): NET: Registered protocol family 16
 4 Time(s): NET: Registered protocol family 17
 4 Time(s): NET: Registered protocol family 2
 4 Time(s): NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
 4 Time(s): NODE_DATA [mem 0x83fff9000-0x83fffdfff]
 4 Time(s): NR_IRQS:16640 nr_irqs:808 16
 4 Time(s): NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
 4 Time(s): NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
 4 Time(s): NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
 4 Time(s): NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
 4 Time(s): NetLabel: Initializing
 4 Time(s): No NUMA configuration found
 4 Time(s): Normal   [mem 0x100000000-0x83fffffff]
 4 Time(s): Normal zone: 118784 pages used for memmap
 4 Time(s): Normal zone: 7602176 pages, LIFO batch:31
 4 Time(s): Offload RCU callbacks from CPUs: 0-15.
 4 Time(s): Offload RCU callbacks from all CPUs
 4 Time(s): On node 0 totalpages: 8372591
 4 Time(s): PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
 4 Time(s): PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
 4 Time(s): PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
 4 Time(s): PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in E820
 4 Time(s): PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
 4 Time(s): PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
 4 Time(s): PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
 4 Time(s): PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
 4 Time(s): PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
 4 Time(s): PERCPU: Embedded 29 pages/cpu @ffff88083fc00000 s87360 r8192 d23232 u131072
 4 Time(s): PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
 4 Time(s): PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009b000-0x0009bfff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009c000-0x0009ffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbc1c5000-0xbeb90fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbeb91000-0xbeb96fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbeb97000-0xbecccfff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbeccd000-0xbecd0fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbecd1000-0xbecf1fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbecf2000-0xbecf2fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbecf3000-0xbed24fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbed25000-0xbef2efff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbef2f000-0xbefeffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbf000000-0xbfffffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc0000000-0xf7ffffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfebfffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfed18fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed19000-0xfed19fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed1a000-0xfed1bfff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed1c000-0xfed1ffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfedfffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xff3fffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff400000-0xffffffff]
 4 Time(s): PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xbeb91000-0xbeb96fff] (24576 bytes)

[...]
```

Comment: Is logwatch running on the syslog server or the servers directly?

Comment: @GdD - It's just 1 server containing everything (application, webserver, database, everything else like Logwatch, etc.).

Comment: Did you check also rotated-out log files? What is the server distribution? Which exact files did you check?

Comment: @Jakuje - No need for the rotated-out log files because the dates went back far enough already. The distro is Ubuntu. And I've tail'ed the file ```/var/log/auth.log```